# AdMob, AdRequest with keywords, setKeywords

Tags: request, admob, keyword, banner, banner-ads

I'm using AdMob and I would like to customize my AdRequeast, so I used the method: setKeywords. I write my keywords for clothing like: trousers skirt, socks, jeans, shirts, sweater...and many more (over 400).

And with keywords the AdBanner is not display on the phone; without the keywords all works fine.

Do you have idea why?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

400 keywords is way way overkill. You would tyically use 3 or 4 at most. Try trimming them down.

Comment: I read on google forum that setKeywords are not supported in AdMob, so it does not make sense to use it. I also used for test 3-4 keywords and I have noticed the differenced.

Comment: it shuld be: and I have NOT noticed the difference